# Unable to limit authentication issuers in a multi-tenant application (Blazor Server App / OpenIDConnect / Azure App Services)

Tags: authentication, azure-web-app-service, openid-connect, multi-tenant, blazor-server-side

I am trying to add multi-tenant authentication and authorization to my Blazor Server App deployed in Azure App Services. The scenario is very basic:

1. allow multitenant authentication (works well)
2. limit authentication to named tenants/issuers (code for this is in the startup.cs)
3. authorizing authenticated users

Step 2 fails though. I can still open the app with an account from a non-verified issuer when I deploy my app in Azure. Here's my code (startup.cs):

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
                    {
                        Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                        // Restrict users to specific belonging to specific tenants
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters 
                        {   ValidateIssuer = true,
                            // Tried first this, but with no effect:
                            // ValidIssuers = new List<string> {
                            //    "https://sts.windows.net/<tenant1>/",
                            //    "https://sts.windows.net/<tenant2>/"
                            //},
                            //So instead tried to use IssuerValidator, but this did not restrict access either:
                            IssuerValidator = ValidateSpecificIssuers
                        };
                    });

            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
//...

private string[] GetAcceptedTenantIds()
        {
            return new[]
            {
            "<tenant1>",
            "<tenant2>",
            };
        }

        public string ValidateSpecificIssuers(string issuer, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
        {
            var validIssuers = GetAcceptedTenantIds().Select(tid => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tid}");
            if (validIssuers.Contains(issuer))
            {
                return issuer;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("The sign-in user's account does not belong to one of the tenants that this Web App accepts users from.");
            }
        }
```

I am using Visual Studio Blazor Server App project template with Multi-organization authentication. No other changes to relevant code sections (except "TenantId": "organizations" in appsettings.json).
I found this [post](https://forums.asp.net/t/2168649.aspx?Microsoft%20AspNetCore%20Authentication%20OpenIdConnect%20TokenValidationParameters%20ValidateIssuer%20true%20requires%20IssuerValidator), where it says that ValidIssuer(s) does not behave as one might expect. That's why I tried using IssuerValidator instead. With the same result unfortunately.

What am I missing? What should I try next?

Comment: Have you tried this sample? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-3-Multi-Tenant/README.md#custom-token-validation-allowing-only-registered-tenants

Comment: Could you please parse your token via https://jwt.ms to check its issuer?

Comment: @StanleyGong I have used 1-WebApp-OIDC/[link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-2-AnyOrg) 1-2-AnyOrg/ from that same tutorial. I chose that one, because onboarding was working fine and I didn't need to partition any data by tenant, and I was a bit lost with the AadIssuerValidator (where does it come from?). Having said that, I was wondering though, might options.Events.OnTokenValidated be a better strategy to check the issuer (vs. TokenValidationParameters)?

Comment: @JimXu I am afraid I was not able to figure out how to get that jwt in the first place. Is it possible to find it in Chrome dev tools?

Comment: @SannaW You can use the fiddler to catch request then you can get jwt.

Comment: @SannaW Besides, could you please check the value of `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` in the Manifest via the portal?

Comment: @JimXu "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null. I can catch that jwt when deployed in localhost, and it looks fine, but when I try to replicate that with my app in Azure I get a wall of code (109lines) in response and I can't locate that jwt from there whatever I do.

Comment: @SannaW Is that you use the same code and it does to work in azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally (thanks to @JimXu, who said I should use fiddler)..
The problem was in my **Azure App Service** and **App Registration** settings:

1. I had App Service Authentication "*On*". So the authentication process was using that (https://login.microsoftonline.com/kmsi redirecting to https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback) instead of my app code (redirecting to https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/singin-oidc) --> *"Off"*
2. *.auth/login/aad/callback* worked because I had also added https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback to my App registration Redirect URIs --> *removed*

ValidIssuers was not enough to restrict users so I had to have that IssuerValidator there. The code looks like this now:

```
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters 
                    {   ValidateIssuer = true,
                        IssuerValidator = ValidateSpecificIssuers
                    };
                });
```

...

```
private string[] GetAcceptedIssuers()
    {
        return new[]
        {
        "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant1>/v2.0",
        "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant2>/v2.0",
        };
    }

public string ValidateSpecificIssuers(string issuer, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
    {
        var validIssuers = GetAcceptedIssuers();
        if (validIssuers.Contains(issuer))
        {
            return issuer;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("The sign-in user's account does not belong to one of the tenants that this Web App accepts users from.");
        }
    }
```